# NetSuite: How to change the total tax amount in a workflow?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to divide my total shipping & handling costs into 3 different buckets, shipping, handling and tax (on the handling).

I currently have a workflow that sets the shipping cost correctly, handling cost correctly (on a Credit Card Sale) but for some reason it doesn't set the tax total correctly.

I think I'm using the wrong field, because in my workflow I tried to just set "Tax Total" = 0.00 and it doesn't work, the tax total is just the same as it was originally. Is there a different field I need to be setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if your line items have a tax code associate with it or it there is a Tax Item applied to the whole transaction?

As far as I know, the 'Tax Total' is computed by NetSuite so it is probably over-writing the value that is being set by the workflow.

Comment: Thanks Rusty. What you say looks to be correct. I got it to work by marking handling on the shipping item as taxable and then NS does just do the calculation and tax update for me. Much appreciated!